# Problems with zoom in HTML (browser window)

Tags: html, css, window, zooming

I have created a small  HTML-Site, but the zoom in my browser completely breaks it. On fullscreen and 100% zoom it looks fine, but when zoombing or resizing the browser window all the elements just resize and move randomly on the screen. What i want is a zoom, that does not move anything but resize the whole page (like zooming an image) (how) is this posible? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must use fixed values.
It seems that you are using percent values for styling your website.
And there is a simple trick that you make a container div and add it a fixed width then you can have percent in child elements.

```
.container { width:900px; margin:0 auto; }
.container .logo { width: 25%; /* 25 percent of 900px */ }
.container .navigation { width:75%; /* 75 percent of 900px */ }
```

You may also need to reset margin and padding values.